# Can't take build because of speech_to_text flutter library

Tags: flutter

Here error output:
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':speech_to_text'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':speech_to_text:classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :speech_to_text
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':speech_to_text' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':speech_to_text' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 15s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           16,0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

I tried to remove speech_to_text plugin

Comment: You need to share some code